# Jenkins 2 - Matrix-based Security

Tags: jenkins

I want to grant permission to an user in order that  see the configuration of a job but can't update it.

I have configured Matrix-based Security (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) and I selected "Read" permission at the Job grid but the user still can't see the configuration of the job.

Is there any way to grant permission to a user for just seeing the configuration of the job not update it?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a duh, but you did save and restart Jenkins after making the changes, right?

Comment: Plugin is not being updated - likely not functional from comments. This may be a better match: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: Under User/Group "Overall", make sure that "Read" is selected there also. In the vanilla non-plugin security settings, Overall Read must be granted so that a user can see anything after they log in. Job Read should work in vanilla settings at that point. The plugin is stacked on the vanilla settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response ScotT. Yes, I did after making changes. The point here is, I don't want to user can create new jobs or update jobs which already exist, I just want to user will able to see the configuration of the jobs. If I select "Read" option at Overall and Job grids then the user can't see job's configuration but can see job list

Comment: Job Read was choosen but it is just allowed to see the Job not its configuration, also,  I really want to user will be able to see the configuration but not modifying it. Does anyone point me to the right direction?